# Create Nested Array From Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to get proper Json data from mysql. I made a lot of progress. Take a look;

I have table like below:

```
name             folder    path
RayMala          787       01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg,04.jpg,05.jpg...
RayMala          788       01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg,04.jpg,05.jpg,06.jpg...
Falitiko         332       01.jpg...
Falitiko         333       01.jpg,02.jpg...
```

My Current Code:Making array from single table cell.

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$nArray = array();
foreach($rows as $value){
    $nArray[] = array('name' => $value['name'], 'folder' => $value['folder'], 'path' => explode(",", $value['path']));
}

print json_encode($nArray);
```

Current JSON Output:See name value repeating.

```
[
    {
        "name": "RayMala",
        "folder": "787",
        "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
    },
    {
        "name": "RayMala",
        "folder": "788",
        "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Falitiko",
        "folder": "333",
        "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
    }
]
```

Wanted JSON Output:

```
[
    {
        "name":"RayMala",
        "random": [
            {
                "folder": "787",
                "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
            },
            {
                "folder": "788",
                "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Falitiko",
        "random": [
            {
                "folder": "332",
                "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
            },
            {
                "folder": "333",
                "Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: do it like this `$nArray[$value['name']] =`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nArray = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
   $nArray[$r["name"]][] = array('folder' => $r['folder'], 'path' => explode(",", $r['path']));
}
$output_arr = array();
foreach($nArray as $key=>$value){
   $output_arr[]=array("name"=>$key,"random"=>$value);
}
echo json_encode($output_arr);
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect but I forgot to add the name key. Because this way I cant call it in Angularjs. I edited the my Wanted Json Output. Could you edit your answer?

Comment: I added an additional foreach loop to get the names into the array. I don't know a way to do it in one loop as you have to check if the name is already existing then.